# Youtube api v3 for get Channel's Show list

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube api v3 for get channel's show list. For that i am using following method as it in document,
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelType=show&part=snippet&channelId=UC55IWqFLDH1Xp7iu1_xknRA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Its give error like 400 Bad Request. Can any one tell me what's wrong wih this api?

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

You need to set type=channel as it says in

> "debugInfo": "code: ERROR_INVALID_FILTER\nlocation: \nhttp status:
>   400\n[debug] Filters on channels are only available when
>   type=channel\n\ncom.google.api.server.core.Fault:
>   ImmutableErrorDefinition{base=BAD_REQUEST, category=USER_ERROR,
>   cause=null, debugInfo=code: ERROR_INVALID_FILTER\nlocation: \nhttp
>   status: 400\n[debug] Filters on channels are only available when
>   type=channel\n, domain=youtube.search, extendedHelp=null,
>   httpHeaders={}, httpStatus=badRequest,
>   internalReason=Reason{arguments={}, cause=null,

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Now this api returns show list. I want this shows video. I am trying to find showid in response but there is nothing like that. So which api i have to use for get channel's shows videos?

Comment: can you please help me on this issue?